# Fill line up with special Character before and after Text

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext

I would like to create a Sublime Text 2 Snippet that fills up the space before and after the Variable I type with spaces.

It should look like this:

```
===========================my_filename.js===========================
```

The Filename should be centered so the number of spaces before and after the Text have to match.
Also I need the overall column width of this line the stay the same. So when I add 2 Characters the number of spaces on each side gets reduced by one.

I think a sample for this would be:

```
spacesLeft  = roundDown((columnWidth/2) - (textSize/2))
spacesRight = roundUp((columnWidth/2) - (textSize/2))
```

But since only RegEx is available in Sublime Snippets I don't see me able, to accomplish this task.

Could Vintagmode help me in any Way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because snippets are essentially static, they wouldn't be able to help you in this case.  However, you could create a plugin to do this relatively easily.  Sublime Text uses python for its plugins.  You can create one by going to Tools > New Plugin.  ST2's API can be found [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and is very impressive.  Essentially, you'll want to store the current selection (your variable) using

```
sel_reg = self.view.sel()[0] # the current selection 'Region'
sel = self.view.substr(sel_reg) # the text within the 'Region'
```

Then generate the ='s

```
signs = ''
each_side = len(80 - len(sel))/2 # 80 is the standard window length, 
                                   # change this to what you want.
                                   # Not sure about how to make it dynamic.
for x in xrange(each_side):
  signs += '='
```

Then replace the current line (`self.view.line(sel)`) with `signs + sel + signs`.

Comment: `sel = " " + re.search("[^/]+$", self.view.file_name()).group(0) + " "` did the job :)